# Cookies appear in the cookies tab but I can't access them with req.headers.cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, next.js

I'm using next.js with express, in my express server I'm setting the cookies and when I go to a route I'm trying to retrieve the cookies, but the cookie is undefined, I'm using a library called [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie)
I can see the cookie in the application tab under cookie, it is set with the right values.

This is how the cookie is set in the express server:

```
res.setHeader(
          "Set-Cookie",
          cookie.serialize("tk", accessToken, {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15, //15 minutes
            httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
            path: "/",
            secure: false,
            expires: expiresIn,
            // sameSite: "none",
          })
        );
```

and this is how I'm trying to read it:

```
const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || "");
```

Login in nextjs:

```
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");

    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      // redirect: "follow",
      credentials: "include", // Don't forget to specify this if you need cookies
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie.parse() didn't work for me. I used this:

```
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookie = context.req.cookies["COOKIENAMEHERE"];
  return {
    props: {
      token: cookie || null,
    },
  };
}
```